# Why my multiprocess queue might be "losing" items?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I've got some code where I want to share objects between processes using queues. I've got a parent:

```
processing_manager = mp.Manager()
to_cacher = processing_manager.Queue()
fetchers = get_fetchers()
fetcher_process = mp.Process(target=fetch_news, args=(to_cacher, fetchers))
fetcher_process.start()
while 1:
    print(to_cacher.get())
```

And a child:

```
def fetch_news(pass_to: Queue, fetchers: List[Fetcher]):
    def put_news_to_query(pass_to: Queue, fetchers: List[Fetcher]):
        for fet in fetchers:
            for news in fet.latest_news():
                print(news)
                pass_to.put(news)
        print("----------------")

    put_news_to_query(pass_to, fetchers)
```

I'm expecting to see N objects printed in `put_news_to_query`, then a line, and then the same objects printed in while loop in a parent. Problem is, objects appear to miss: if I get, say, 8 objects printed in `put_news_to_query` I get only 2-3 objects printed in while loop. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't even debug it properly: PyCharm's debugger is "Collecting data..." infinitely until it hangs if I place a breakpoint somewhere in children process

Comment: I would try adding in mp.Event() to control the flow

Comment: @TeejayBruno - I don't see how that would help. A MP queue should not also need an event. What would it even suppose to do? Wait on the event then wait on the queue? Or should the sender only send one thing, wait on the event, send anther thing?

Comment: You should get mingled prints from both processes and then then a line and maybe a few extra prints from the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, it was something related to in which order put and get statements were executed. Basically, some of the objects from parent's print were printed before the line. If you struggle with something like this, I'd recommend adding something to distinguish prints, like this:

```
print(f"Worker: {news}")
print(f"Main: {to_cacher.get()}")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer, unless the answer is that the code is already working. I've just modified the code to make it a running example of the same technique. The data gets from child to parent without data loss.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random

def worker(pass_to):
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(random.randint(0,10)/1000)
        print('child', i)
        pass_to.put(i)
    print("---------------------")
    pass_to.put(None)

def main():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    to_cacher = manager.Queue()
    fetcher = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(to_cacher,))
    fetcher.start()
    while 1:
        msg = to_cacher.get()
        if msg is None:
            break
        print(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```